# FreeTextAnswer alternative

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

The `FreeTextAnswer()` mimics a textarea in HTML. Is there a way to mimic a text input, something like `FreeTextInput()`?

Here is the [QuestionForm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html) documentation, but I think the `FreeTextAnswer()` is the closest alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `NumberOfLinesSuggestion` parameter. Setting that to 1 will convert from textarea to a single-line text input. [See the developer forum for details](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=558682&#558682).